# PlistBuddy - Copying from one plist to another

Tags: macos, shell, sh, plist, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to copy the Root Dictionary from a plist file and adding it to another plist file

```
git clone https://github.com/rahulkatariya/osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized.git

mv osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized/Solarized\ Dark.terminal osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized/Solarized\ Dark.plist

solarizedDark=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print" osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized/Solarized\ Dark.plist 2>&1`

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :Window\ Settings:Solarized\ Dark dict $solarizedDark" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
```

#### Error

The output still creates an empty dictionary of Solarized Dark inside Window Settings Dictionary but with 0 items

[image: Terminal Plist] 
Here is the plist i am trying to copy

[image: Solarized Dark Plist]

Comment: You probably want `2>&1` rather than `2>$1`

Comment: Thanks. My Bad, Now i get this error `usr/libexec/PlistBuddy: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and paste in the **entire output** so I can see if the error occurs on the first or the second invocation of `PlistBuddy`.

Comment: This error occurs when i try `echo $solarizedDark`. And the last line `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :Window\ Settings:Solarized\ Dark dict $solarizedDark" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` adds a empty dict in the terminal.plist

Comment: I don't think this is the way to go. I would use more traditional UNIX file manipulation commands.  Actually I would use `python`.

Comment: Try `"Add ':Window Settings:Solarized Dark'"`

Comment: @MarkSetchell - This doesn't work :(.

Comment: You don't want `$(solarizedDark)` as that will try to execute a command called `solarizedDark`. You probably mean `${solarizedDark}` which will output the contents of the variable with that name rather than run a command with that name.

Comment: Worked and value of `$solarizedDark` is also echoed. But still can't insert into the new plist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**

I added an empty Dict and then used the Merge command of PlistBuddy to add all entries of the file inside the new dict like below

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ':Window Settings:Solarized Dark' dict" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Merge 'osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized/Solarized Dark.plist' ':Window Settings:Solarized Dark'" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
```